# Connect draggable to sortable only if visible?

Tags: jquery-ui

In the jquery ui docs for draggable, we can specify a sortable to connect to:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ connectToSortable: 'ul#myList' });
```

is it possible to connect to a sortable only when its visibility is set to 'visible'? Something like:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ connectToSortable: 'ul#myList:visibility=visible' });
```

I don't want to let the user drop elements on my sortable target unless it is visible,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ connectToSortable: '#myList:visible' });
```

Give it a shot and see if it works. :)